# OpenSSH as SFTP server: Trigger successful and faulty changes

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I am using the current OpenSSH version on Debian 7.7 Whezzy, which is, according to *dpkg*, 1:6.0p1-4+deb7u2.

I configured OpenSSH to allow clients to connect using SFTP, and read and modify (upload or replace) arbitrary files in a chroooted environment.

I want a script to be triggered whenever a change (deletion, upload or replacement) occurs, and, if possible, as well if the change succeeded or failed.

For example, if Alice uploads a file */foo/bar.png*, a script `notify.sh alice /home/alice/foo/bar.png UPLOAD SUCCESS` would be invoked.

Is there a way to realize this?

Comment: Look into [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK OpenSSH doesn't have a support for that. <opinion>The probable reason behind that, that the OpenSSH guys favorize the minimal feature, maximal security concept which is quite visible on their other projects, too.</opinion> But it is not unconditionally a problem.

1. You can do this by watching the system log, and setting up condition for that (at least [syslog-ng](http://syslog-ng.org) can do this).
2. There is [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) for the task. It is a daemon, using the inotify feature of the linux kernel to call scripts, triggered by file changes.

Comment: would this allow to detect interrupted uploads (e.g. the connection of Alice gets interrupted during file transfer)?

Comment: @muffel I would do this with log watching, incron can see only file operations.

Comment: @muffel For interrupted downloads, see [How to detect or log interrupted uploads with OpenSSH SFTP server?](http://serverfault.com/q/652629/168875)